# Never create frame in ediff

Tags: frames, ediff

In general, I dislike frames. Right now, I'm using

```el
(setq ediff-window-setup-function #'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

To ensure that `ediff` does not create a frame when it starts.

However, certain commands, like `ediff-show-registry` still open up new frames.

Is there any way I can completely disable the creation of frames in `ediff`?

Comment: How about modifying `ediff-skip-unsuitable-frames`, or commenting that out entirely within `ediff-show-registry` -- e.g., comment out:  `(ediff-skip-unsuitable-frames 'ok-unsplittable)`?

Comment: While you are at it, consider searching the source of the `ediff`-family of libraries for  `(make-frame` and you'll find a few places that need fixing to suit your preferences.  Your request is certainly reasonable, and would merit (in my opinion) a feature request to the author and/or Emacs team -- most people will assume `ediff-setup-windows-plain` should apply across the board without the various `make-frame` exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

There is an internal predicate in `ediff-init.el`, called `ediff-window-display-p`.  When I redefined it (after loading ediff, of course) like so, everything works in a single frame, including the function you mentioned as a problem:

```el
(defun ediff-window-display-p () nil)
```

I do agree with @lawlist that this is a nice feature request -- to fix `ediff-window-setup-function`.

Comment: This might be better written `(advice-add 'ediff-window-display-p :override #'ignore)`, which can more easily be reversed with `advice-remove` (plus it doesn't require loading ediff first).

Comment: @npostavs great!  Thanks for the smarter code!

Comment: I tried this, but it unfortunately caused ediff to stop using my custom window setup function.

Comment: @tboyce12 That's confusing... why do you have a custom window set up function if you don't want new windows (i.e. frames) to show? What does the function do?

Comment: I do want new windows, but not new frames. The default `ediff-setup-windows-plain` takes over the whole frame -- I want to keep my "context" windows open (eg notes and other files). So I wrote a custom window setup function (uses custom display-buffer powered by ace-window to choose where to maybe split windows and display new buffers). It seems that when Ediff boots up it checks this `ediff-window-display-p` and if false, bypasses the custom window setup function and uses `ediff-setup-windows-plain`.

So for my custom setup, I'll either avoid `ediff-show-registry`, or write custom command.