# Ediff in one frame

Tags: ediff

I want to start Ediff in a single frame the way `pacfiles` does:

[image: Ediff using pacfiles]

Right now it opens the control panel in a separate frame.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://stackoverflow.com/q/1680750 and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17064

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `ediff-setup-windows-plain`, which does everything in one frame.

`M-x customize-variable` `RET` `ediff-window-setup-function` and set the value to `ediff-setup-windows-plain`.